# IE9 dropdown menu not showing

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-9

I have a site built in Wordpress using Twitter Bootstrap.
Dropdown menu kicks in at bellow of 1200px and it works properly on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and some versions of IE.
But, on IE9 (tested on Win7) it isnt showing at all.

I tried adding/including html5shiv, IE=Edge tag, everything i could think of that could make it work, but no luck.

Anybody have any advices?
URL is http://tinyurl.com/oyasnfn

Comment: Hi Mariola there is only one submenu below contact menu and its showing fine in IE9 I am checking on windows 7 with ie10 browser and changed mode to IE9

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

I know about that one, but above the slider there should be main navigation menu which isnt showing :\